# How to disable "Delete" button for individual pages

Tags: sharepoint-server

Is it possible to disable delete button for individual pages for few users ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you want users to only read items then use the Read permission. Edit the page permissions, break permission inheritance, remove unwanted users or groups. Edit users and groups for read only access and set their permissions to "Read".

At a list or library level:

If you want users to create new items, but not delete, create a new permission level with the same settings as "Contribute". Call it "Contribute without delete" or similar.  Edit the new permission level and untick the "Delete" permission.

Next, edit the list or library permissions. Break permission inheritance. Remove unwanted users and groups. Add or edit users or groups and assign them the permission level "Contribute without delete". These people can now create new items but not delete them.